# My Mac shuts down if left closed for a long period, even for a long time. Then the power button must be held to a long time to start up

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, osx-mountain-lion

My Mac (Retina, Mid 2012) running OSX 10.8.5 sometimes shuts down while closed, even if it is plugged in. When it does this, I need to hold the power button for a long time, 15 seconds or more. I don't know why this is happening. Note: I do have rEFInd installed and I'm dual booting Ubuntu.

Here is my power settings. I know AutoPowerOff Enabled is 1 but the delay is 40 hours, and this problem happens after a significantly shorter time than 40 hours.

My ideal configuration would be that the computer either sleeps or hibernates when the lid is closed, and only shuts down if the battery is about to die.

[image: Power information]

Comment: You could try disabling standby mode and autopoweroff with `sudo pmset -a standby 0 autopoweroff 0` or disabling Power Nap from System Preferences.

Comment: Power Nap was already off. I ran that command, I'll tell you what happens overnight, as that's typically when the problem shows up.